# Path Redirect Import module getting "Line 1 contains invalid status code"

Tags: 7, redirection, importing-exporting, path-aliases

I created a CSV file without the headers:

```
From URL    To URL  Redirect Status Redirect Language
```

But the file doesn't import and I get error messages:

> "Line 1 contains invalid status code"

My CSV file:

```
“file/sitemap.xml”, “sitemap.xml”,  “301”,  “en”
```

Comment: You stated some facts. Please ask question.

Comment: what are the issue why csv file not import

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the csv row you provided, it looks like that the syntax is not correct:

1. Try to separate fields only with ',' and not with ', ' (comma + whitespace)
2. Use regular double `"` quotes or single quotes `'`, not these opening `“` and closing `”` double quotes you get when using word processors. I guess for the last two columns (status code and language) you won't need quotes at all.
3. You may also remove the headers line from the csv and check the "no headers" option if it contains non-ascii bytes.

See also this tutorial: [Module of the Day: Path Redirect Import](https://swsblog.stanford.edu/blog/module-day-path-redirect-import).